# Detect click outside a <td> using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a `td` like below.

```
<td class="volunteer" id="422" data-select2-id="select2-data-422">
    <select multiple="" data-select2-id="select2-data-1-dpng" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
        //more code here
    </select>
    <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="select2-data-2-ooba" style="width: 16px;">
      //more code here    
    </span>
</td>
```

I would like to detect click outside of this `td`. I used below jQuery code.

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
  alert('hello');
  $('.volunteer *').unbind('click');
});
```

But it is not working.

Comment: you will have to detect the click on it's parent component, i don't think it's possible to detect it "outside" the `td`, maybe everywhere else is possible, but just a specific range outside of `td` doesn't work

Comment: Thanks @tsamridh86. What does it mean ` just a specific range outside of td doesn't work` ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd add the listener to document.body then I'd check if the event target is or is contained in `volunteer`

```
$(document.body).click(function (e) {
  alert('hello');
  if (!e.target.closest('.volunteer')) {
    $('td.volunteer *').unbind('click');
  }
});
```